# componentDidUpdate is called at first render although anything doesn't change

Tags: reactjs

## What I want to do

When `state` changes, I would like to fetch data from API and set it to `state`.

## Problem

**When I load a page, `componentDidUpdate` is automatically emitted although anything doesn't change and this is initial render.**

I am beginner to `React`.
I would like to get data from API when I input some data and `state` changes.
However, when I load a page I got an error that `cannot property map of undefined`.
Apparently, `componentDidUpdate` is called for some reasons when the page is first rendered.
In fact, I compared `prevState.line` to `this.state.line`, and then I found `prevState.line` `undefined`.

I mean, `componentDidUpdate` is emitted before `""` that is an initial value of `this.state.line` is set to `this.state.line`.

**I just would like to prevent `componentDidUpdate` from being initially called.**
If you know a way to do that, I would like you to tell me that and why it is happening.

Thank you very much.

===========             ============           ============

My code is like this.

```
class User_Add_PickUp_Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      owner: this.props.loginUser,
      lines: '',
      stations: '',
      textInput: '',
      allLines: '',
      allStations: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  spreadAndSetState = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [key]:value });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Original is ' + this.state.lines)
    axios
      .get('http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getLines&prefecture=TOKYO')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.setState({ allLines: res.data.response.line })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState){
    console.log(prevState)
    console.log(this.state)
    if(prevState.lines != this.state.lines){
      axios.get('http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getStations&line=' + this.state.lines)
      .then((res)=> {
        //
        // res.data.response.stations is going to be an array
        // 
        res.data.response.station.map((station) => {
        this.spreadAndSetState(this.state.allStations, station.name)
        })
      })
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.spreadAndSetState(name,value)
  };

  render() {
    const { owner, lines, stations, textInput, allLines, allStations } = this.state;
    if (allLines === '') {
      return <CircularProgress />;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Add Pickup Places</h2>
          <select name="lines" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Choose a line</option>
            {allLines.map((line) => {
              return <option value={line}>{line}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
          <select name="lines" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Choose a station</option>
            {allLines.map((line) => {
              return <option value={line}>{line}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` isn't (and is never) called on the initial render (i.e. when the component mounts). Are you sure `res.data.response.station` exists? Can you update question and share the response object (you can get this from the network tab in your browser's dev tools, or try `console.log(res)` in the then block)?

Comment: Fortunately, I just found what was wrong. I should have put `prevProps`  before `prevState`. Now I am having another problem but I found how to solve this question. But, thank you for your really quick comment.

Comment: Ah, right, good catch, I missed it as well.